# class_replaceMethod category method return nil

Tags: ios

I use UIViewController category to do method replace in iOS. 
I write a category method `- (void)sw_viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated` to replace UIViewController `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated`.

The category codes bellow :

```
- (void)exchangeImp {
    Class aClass = object_getClass(self);
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(viewWillAppear:);
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(sw_viewWillAppear:);

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, swizzledSelector);
    IMP result = class_replaceMethod(aClass, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    NSLog(@"result is %p", result);}

- (void)sw_viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
     NSLog(@"There do custome things");}
```

the result always return `nil`, but as far as I know, if method already exist,  `class_replaceMethod` will return the old `IMP`. Isn't the old `IMP` should be `sw_viewWillAppear:`? Why it return nil?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I know why. Because I call `exchangeImp` in `ViewController` not `UIViewController` ! `ViewController` is subclass of `UIViewController`. I write `UIViewController`'s category, so the category method will be in `UIViewController` method list, not  `ViewController`! That's why 'class_replaceMethod' always return nil.